# MSXML3 and MSXML6 / What Object/Functtion is internally used?

Tags: com, msxml

I have to maintanance a old Software that officially uses MSXML3. When I look for the Exports of a Project Library (with dumpbin) I find a Function named GetNodeText:

```
    560 22F 0003CA40 
    ?GetNodeText@CBgsXML@@SA?AVCString@@V?$_com_ptr_t@V?$_com_IIID@UIXMLDOMNode@MSXML2@@$1?_GUID_2933bf80_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60@@3U__s_GUID@@A@@@@PBD@Z
```

When I have a look to the registered COM-Interfaces and search for "{2933bf80-7b36-11d2-b20e-00c04f983e60}" (from Export) I find the following Entry:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2933BF80-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}]
    @="IXMLDOMNode"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2933BF80-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}\ProxyStubClsid]
    @="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2933BF80-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}\ProxyStubClsid32]
    @="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2933BF80-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}\TypeLib]
    "Version"="6.0"
    @="{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}"
```

If I look for the registered Typelib from IXMLNode I find this Entry:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}]

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\3.0]
    @="Microsoft XML, v3.0"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\3.0\0]

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\3.0\0\win32]
    @="C:\\Windows\\system32\msxml3.dll"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\3.0\FLAGS]
    @="0"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\4.0]
    @="Microsoft XML, v4.0"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\4.0\0]

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\4.0\0\win32]
    @="C:\\Windows\\system32\\msxml4.dll"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\4.0\FLAGS]
    @="0"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\4.0\HELPDIR]
    @=""

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\6.0]
    @="Microsoft XML, v6.0"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\6.0\0]

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\6.0\0\win32]
    @="C:\\Windows\\system32\\msxml6.dll"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\6.0\FLAGS]
    @="0"
```

The Function Looks like this:

```
    CString ClassA::GetNodeText( IXMLDOMNodePtr spNode, LPCTSTR pszXPath )
    {
        ASSERT( ::AfxIsValidString( pszXPath ) );

        if( spNode )
            spNode = spNode->selectSingleNode( pszXPath );

        return ( spNode != NULL ) ? (LPCWSTR) spNode->text : NULL;
    }
```

It seems that the Function selectSingleNode (function of msxml3.dll) wrapped internally the same COM-Object (IXMLDOMNode) like selectSingleNode (function of msxml6.dll).

Isn't it so? Or I'am wrong? How does it work with the Functions?

Comment: Well, no.  IXMLDOMNodePtr is a C++ smart pointer type, a wrapper for the IXMLDOMNode interface.  It is auto-generated by the #import directive.  You should use `#import "c:\windows\system32\msxml3.dll"` in your program to generate the same type.